# Errors when trying to get kubectl completion working

Tags: arch-linux, zsh, kubernetes

My question is why do I see this error when trying to get `kubectl` autocomplete working in my terminal. I really only care about getting the `zsh` one working. I'm simply using some other examples of other strange issues in the `bash` version as well for troubleshooting purposes. Here are some basic contexts.

OS: Arch Linux

Kernel: 5.13.9-arch1-1

Terminal: alacritty, kitty, urxvt

Shell: zsh (oh-my-zsh)

Kubectl version: 1.21.3

I would also like to note, I have been trying this across many different `kubectl` versions all the way going back from 1.17, and across many arch kernel releases, terminal version, and zsh versions. It has been the same issue/error. If it matters or not, I am usually in a tmux session, but I experience this in or out of a tmux session.

Now, the error

```bsh
$ source <(kubectl completion zsh)
__kubectl_type:cd:11: no such file or directory: 0
```

It's the same in any terminal I run this in.

Now, in bash

```bsh
# first I run `/bin/bash` from my `zsh` prompt to switch, maybe there is a better way to test this?
$ /bin/bash
$ source <(kubectl completion bash)
$ kubectl get [tab twice]
# on the same line with no line break, it turns my current line into
$ kubectl get bash: _get_comp_words_by_ref: command not found
bash: _get_comp_words_by_ref: command not found

Display all 153 possibilities? (y or n)
...
```

At first I think; "Cool, maybe it kinda worked?". So I type `y` and it just outputs all of my home dir.

I would like to note in my testing this. I've tried all combinations of zsh and bash in and out of tmux and in all three terminals (alacritty, kitty, and urxvt). The results are identical.

How do I even troubleshoot this?

Comment: "in and out of tmux and in all three terminals (alacritty, kitty, and urxvt)": That's completely irrelevant. Your terminal has no influence on how completions are generated.

Comment: Did you read and follow all of the instructions output by `kubectl completion -h`?

Comment: @MarlonRichert Thanks for pointing that out. Just wanted to make sure I cover my basis. I had a few people I explained this to say "Your terminal is messed up". So I thought maybe it was impacting it. For you advice to check the help. I did not, I had been using the kube docs for instructions. But I checked your advice. It told me to `kubectl completion zsh > "${fpath[1]}/_kubectl"`. But I wanted to see what was in my `$fpath[1]`. It was set to `~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/docker`. I didn't think that was the best so I set it to `$fpath[5]` which was `~/.oh-my-zsh/completions`. While starting a ...

Comment: continued from above. While starting a fresh terminal session. There are not errors. I'm assuming OMZsh knows about this completion dir and probably loads it. Maybe it doesn't. But tab completion does not work. It wants to autocomplete from whatever files and folders are in my `$PWD`. So I added `source ~/.oh-my-zsh/completions/_kubectl` to my `~/.zshrc` file like the `kubectl completion -h` suggestions for `bash`. However now I get this same error. Just once on startup. But when I try to tab complete, it just spews out the error until I Ctrl+C.

Comment: You didn’t say in your question that you are using `oh-my-zsh`. That’s pretty important. What happens if you don’t use `oh-my-zsh`? Also, it would help if you could post your `.zshrc` file. Oh, and don’t write very long comments. Instead, update your question.

Comment: Above all, try to reduce your question to a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).